# Postgres Migration 9.2.1 to 9.2.4

Tags: postgresql

While migrating the Postgres version 9.2.1 to 9.2.4. I encountered the following error.

> The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "eddie".
>   initdb: directory "../data" exists but is not empty
>   This user must also own the server process.
>   If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
>   the directory "../data" or run initdb
>   with an argument other than "../data".
>   The database cluster will be initialized with locale "C".
>   The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

The issue occurs while running ***initdb.exe***. I checked no other processes are using the data folder. I am working in windows. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: No upgrade is necessary; initdb doesn't need to run.

Comment: For a minor upgrade there is no need to run initdb. Just install the new binaries. Are you aware that 9.2 is [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)? If you do need to use an unsupported version you should at least install the latest minor release which is 9.2.24